# How to configure 2 databases in MyBatis using MyBatis-Spring

Tags: spring, datasource, mybatis

I am trying to configure 2 different datasources in my application as it is required.

My configuration in the AppContext.xml is as follows:

```
<bean id="dataSourceA" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>  
     <property name="url" value="datasourceAURL"/>  
     <property name="username" value="aaaa"/>  
     <property name="password" value="pppp"/>    
</bean>
      <bean id="dataSourceB" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">  
     <property name="driverClassName" value="com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver"/>  
     <property name="url" value="datasourceBURL"/>  
     <property name="username" value="bbbb"/>  
     <property name="password" value="cccc"/>    
</bean>

<bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">  
           <property name="basePackage" value="com/ex/myBatis/mappings" />  
      </bean> 

      <bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">  
     <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceA" />  
     <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.ex.myBatis.entities"/>  
</bean>
      <bean id="sqlSession" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">  
     <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory" />  
      </bean>

      <bean id="sqlSessionFactory1" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">  
     <property name="dataSource" ref="configDataSource" />  
     <property name="typeAliasesPackage" value="com.ex.myBatis.entities"/>  
      </bean>

     <bean id="sqlSession1" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate">  
    <constructor-arg index="0" ref="sqlSessionFactory1" />  
     </bean>

     <bean id="callService" class="com.ex.myBatis.Service.callService">
    <property name="sqlSession" ref="sqlSession1" />
     </bean>
```

But while accessing the bean I am getting the below Exception

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'callService': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not
>   autowire method: public final void
>   org.mybatis.spring.support.SqlSessionDaoSupport.setSqlSessionTemplate(org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate);
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type [org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionTemplate] is
>   defined: expected single matching bean but found 2:
>   sqlSession,sqlSession1

Please somebody help me in figuring out the issue.
Also please suggest me if there is someother way to configure 2 Datasources.

Comment: Can somebody help me out in fixing this issue??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is mostly correct. The problem you face is that you use autowiring to inject one of `callService` dependencies.

Seems that you use `SqlSessionDaoSupport` and its sqlSessionTemplate field is autowired. There are two templates defined so spring cannot automatically wire dependencies. You need specify correct template manually.